# Distort a "path" in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael, vector-graphics

I was wondering if it is possible in RaphaelJS to distort any shape/path for example if I had a shape within a bounding box of 0,0 10,0 10,10 0,10 and lets say the shape had handles at these points and I dragged point 10,10 to 11,15 ... at this point I want to distort the shape to fit the new bounding box.

Imagine the shape is complex, like this http://jsfiddle.net/8hMkC/

If it has to be images thats not too much of a problem (if even that is possible?)

Ta

Answer (score 2):

You can play around with the viewbox using javascript.
http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/QqcwX/

Add a new element (a circle or something) that stands for a button and handle click/drag events. Then you can change viewbox coordinates.

Comment: nice, but I was more hoping to change the perspective rather then zoom/pan around. Is that possible using the viewbox properties and methods?

Comment: I don't know what you really mean by perspective. Isn't that tiger distorted enough?

Comment: ah ok.. I looked at it in IE... has to work in IE... (if it didnt I would just use css 3d transform) I was hoping to get more of a 3D warp to it, with one edge getting bigger and the opposite getting smaller. The closest I found was this http://elbertf.com/raphael/free_transform/ but it only skews rather than creating a perspective transform.

Comment: ah, ok, so you're talking 3D...bit more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of. I'm assuming you want to be able to skew, warp and/or generally distort an arbitrary shape within the confines of a bounding box. This would involve converting any non-path primitive (circles,rects etc.)  to paths and then calculating changes to all node points therein. I'm not saying this can't be done, but you don't get it for free out of the box, so to speak. If this **can** be done, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: If I'm honest, it doesn't have to be RaphaelJS, it could be anything. I just want to be able to warp/distort an image to give it perspective, but I'd like it to work in older IE browsers as well.